# Look inside objects in the Xcode 4 debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I understand that when you reach a breakpoint while debugging in Xcode you can hover the mouse pointer over objects and see their properties. But with most objects you only get a few of the properties. The rest are hidden. Trying this with a CLLocation object is next to useless.

Is there another way to peer inside this object while debugging?
Do I just have to resort to using NSLog to get what I want?

Comment: Check out the answers to this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249108/intelligent-obj-c-variable-contents-while-debugging-in-xcode

Comment: another thread that arrives at @kevboh's answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112796/how-to-view-contents-of-nsdictionary-variable-in-xcode-debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As box pointed out, the gdb `po` command will print out whatever a varname points to. Xcode's debugger panel (the bottom pane in Xcode4) will also list out all objects in the current scope and allow you to view their ivars by clicking the disclosure buttons next to the objects. For Apple classes, though, this doesn't work so great, so I'd rely more on `po`, NSLog, and Apple's docs.

Answer (score 2):

use the command:  po VARNAME This will print out the value for you

Comment: I try this with myLocation.horrizontalAccuracy and I get "member not found". Does it only work for variables, and not for methods on those variables?

Answer (score 0):

Create a -(NSString *)description method for whatever object you're trying to view.

At a breakpoint, right click on the variable **in the local/global variable list** (next to Console output) and click `Print Description of "..."`.  This will print out whatever details you want.

Comment: it's one of Apple's classes. Do you mean create a category with a description method?